# How to show FPS meter in Chrome on (Android) settop box?

Tags: android, google-chrome, frame-rate, television

I want to show video's FPS using HTML5 tag in Chrome on settop box(android)

In Chrome 29, I can use `chrome://flags/#show-fps-counter` to use FPS meter.
But latest Version(50.+), I can't find it any more.

How to show FPS meter on android settop box?