# Is there a keyboard shortcut to show or hide 'FPS meter' in Chromium versions 60+?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, chromium, kiosk

Analyzing an HTML-5 application which makes heavy use of GPU-enabled animations, I would like to constantly check the FPS rate in an environment in which Chrome/Chromium is started with the `--kiosk` startup flag. Currently, I use Chromium in version 60+.

Most of us know how to *en-* or *disable* this feature in Chrome/Chromium by selecting the checkbox `FPS meter` in regular mode (see: [[1]](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings), [[2]](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#rendering)). I already found the startup flag `--show-fps-counter` which shows the GPU debug box upon startup [[3]](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). However, the official developer documentation provided by Google does not mention ways to use a keyboard shortcut to toggle the display of the FPS meter tool.

So my **question** is:

1. Is there an (un-)official **keyboard shortcut** to show/hide the FPS meter when Chrome/Chromium is launched in `--kiosk` mode? If so: what is it?

Questions which I already checked/screened and which did not provide a useful answers:

- [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038065/show-fps-meter-chrome-33), refers to an outdated Chrome version (v33),
- [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781146/how-to-show-fps-meter-in-chrome-on-android-settop-box), refers to Android settop boxes and, as of today, has no answer,
- [[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013925/how-to-toggle-chromes-fps-meter-programmatically?noredirect=1&lq=1), refers to JavaScript and a programmatic activation of the FPS meter (again: no answer).

Any suggestions based on official sources are much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to enable this flag with your chromium version [--ash-debug-shortcuts](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#ash-debug-shortcuts). 
Because if you have a look at the [accelerator_table.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/ash/accelerators/accelerator_table.cc#L88) you can see that there should be a shortcut to toggle the fps counter.

Comment: @FlorianDe It seems to be only included for Chrome OS now (see [ash - historical notes](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/ash#historical-notes)).

Answer (score 4):

The FPS counter, being part of the DevTools, can be toggled programmatically over the [Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP)](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Overlay#method-setShowFPSCounter). An example using Puppeteer is [available here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools-without-devtools) on the Google Developers site.

So a clumsy but working solution would be writing a script that toggles the FPS counter over CDP, and assign a hotkey to it in your OS. You might want to check the [awesome-devtools](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/awesome-chrome-devtools#protocol-driver-libraries) repo to choose a CDP client in your favorite language.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I was asking for a plain *keyboard shortcut*-based approach. A programmatic solution is not what I‘m looking for as I want to activate the FPS meter for any website, independent from having/hacking the source code.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this solution is useful for you ,
first download an extension called [FPS extension](http://chrome://extensions/?id=gdkkmimldhefhmmmlalioafomdlahcog)
then in extensions panel go to keyboard shortcuts and add a shortcut for this extension,
this way you can turn it on and off when ever you want. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can enable that in the Dev Tools area via Ctrl + Shift + J > Console Drawer > 3-dot menu > Rendering > FPS meter.

There is no keyboard shortcut for this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I knew this manual approach via the Dev Tools already. My requirement is a keyboard only approach.